# Ordering comments on a forum topic by rating provided by Rate module, whilst retaining the correct threading

Tags: comments, 10

I have a forum with threaded comments. Each comment has a like button provided by the Rate module (which uses the Voting API).
I want to order the comments on the forum post by the rating count value. I've started looking at the hook_query_TAG_alter() hook but I'm not getting very far.

Comment: Is this helpful? https://www.hashbangcode.com/article/drupal-8-custom-ordering-comments